# Where to find C #pragma syntax parameters

Tags: c, gcc, arm64, pragma

Where to find C #pragma  syntax parameters.
i can't find a specific description in compiler doc,and also in c99 manual

find #pragma helper for specify paltform, such as for aarch64 platform, C language, cross-compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc

Comment: Pragmas are very compiler specific. You need to check your compiler documentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but in compiler documentation, i can't find detailed description，only have some Simple description

Comment: @wohlstad  have updated, cross-compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc, please help me, thanks

Comment: [Pragmas Accepted by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Pragmas.html#Pragmas) If you wonder about some specific pragma then [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have got it, but  it's only have some simple description.  such as i can't find `#pragma section`  description， and  i want to learn the full syntax, including all parameters, so there is no question about some sepcific parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole purpose of `#pragma` is to provide a directive which compilers should ignore if they don't recognize it and thereby allow a means to port code using non-standard language features between compilers.

---

The C standard C17 6.10.6 only standardizes 3 pragmas:

> `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT` *on-off-switch*
> `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` *on-off-switch*
> `#pragma STDC CX_LIMITED_RANGE` *on-off-switch*

All other pragmas are compiler-specific, by their very nature.

---

> Where to find C #pragma syntax parameters

In 6.10.6 of any standard between C99 and C17:

> `# pragma` *pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub>* *new-line*

Meaning that a pragma may be followed by a number of pre-processor tokens, which in turn means that almost anything goes.

There is also the `_Pragma` operator (6.10.9) using the syntax:

> `_Pragma (` *string-literal* `)`

This behaves the same as `#pragma` but you provide a string instead of preprocessor tokens. This allows one to use `_Pragma` inside function-like macros.

---

As for finding out which pragmas that are supported for a particular compiler for a particular system, that's another story. For example gcc specific ones, both for all gcc compilers as well as for various target ports: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html#Pragmas

Comment: thanks for your  answer ， i have got  above message,  but i want to finding out which pragmas that are supported for a particular compiler for a particular system, suah as how to use `#pragma section` in aarch64 platform, C language, cross-compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc

Comment: @Taoo I'm not sure if such a pragma even exists for gcc? I know of a few other compilers that support similar commands as `#pragma section`, but I haven't used that with gcc. The gcc documentation as usual leaves a lot to be desired. In my experience, you'd rather use gcc function attributes https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes if you want to allocate something in a particular section `__attribute__ ((section(my_memory))` etc.